# I am writing a jest snapshot testing, the component is using the redux, why it is giving me TS error,

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, react-redux, jestjs

Hello I am writing snapshot testing in jest with TS and React js, component is getting the state from redux store, so I have setup mock store and provided it all the initial state, test is failing , the error relates to probably TS

```
const userInfo = {
  gender: null,
  height: "",
  weight: "",
  age: "",
  fitPreference: 0,
  email: null,
  emailConfirmed: null,
}
const customer = {
  customerLogo: 'customerLogo',
  customerName: 'CustomerName',
  customerType: 'CustomerType',
}



const mockStore = configureMockStore();
const store = mockStore({
  userInfo, 
  canChangeSizeId: true,
  customer,
  requestId: undefined
});

it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = create(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <SelectGender  />
        </Provider>
      )
      .toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
at the line while calling component <SelectGender  />

 error TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<(Pick<Props, "updateUserGender" | "userInfo" | "customer" | "requestId" | "canChangeSizeId" | "history" | "location" | "match" | "staticContext"> & WithTranslationProps) | (ClassAttributes<...> & ... 1 more ... & WithTranslationProps), "i18n" | ... 4 more ... | "useSuspense">': history, location, match
```

Now, even if I will provide those properties, it will still gives error

```
const selectGenderProps = {
  userInfo,
  updateUserGender: jest.fn(param => null),
  canChangeSizeId: true,
  customer,
  requestId: '1'
}

{...selectGenderProps}
```

New error is here

```
Type '{ userInfo: { gender: any; height: string; weight: string; age: string; fitPreference: number; email: any; emailConfirmed: any; }; updateUserGender: Mock<any, [any]>; canChangeSizeId: boolean; customer: { ...; }; requestId: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<(Pick<Props, "updateUserGender" | "userInfo" | "customer" | "requestId" | "canChangeSizeId" | "history" | "location" | "match" | "staticContext"> & WithTranslationProps) | (ClassAttributes<...> & ... 1 more ... & WithTranslationProps), "i18n" | ... 4 more ... | "useSuspense">': history, location,
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states that `SelectGender` component requires such properties like `updateUserGender`, etc. But now you render this component without any props at all. So either update `SelectGender` type, so that it does not require such properties, or provide them during render

Comment: I have updated my question please check it now

Comment: @UmarJaved can you provide SelectGender type?

Comment: It's requiring the `RouteComponentProps` from react-router: `history`, `location`, `match`.  So you need to either provide them or make it so that they are not required.